# Ruby: How to split lines read from a file into a two dimensional array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, io

For a little thing, I want to store some info in a file and read  from it in such a way, that I have a two-dimensional array at the end.

Let's say this is the content of the config file:

```
Banana:Yellow
Apple:Red
```

This is the code I came up with:

```
a = File.read("config.txt")
b = a.split("\n")
k = Array.new
b.each { |x| k.push(x.split(":"))}
print k
```

It works, but surely there must be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do as below using [`IO::readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-readlines) and [`String#splt`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-split)

```
File.readlines("config.txt").map { |str| str.split(":") }
```

Or, using [`CSV::read`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read)

```
require 'csv'

CSV.read("path/to/file", 'rb', :col_sep => ':')
# => [["Banana", "Yellow"], ["Apple", "Red"]]
```

With CSV, you can *skip* lines, that you don't want to process using the option `:skip_lines` :

> When set to an object responding to match, every line matching it is considered a comment and ignored during parsing. When set to a String, it is first converted to a Regexp. When set to nil no line is considered a comment. If the passed object does not respond to match, *ArgumentError* is thrown.

Suppose I have a file `test.txt` with the content as :-

```
Banana:Yellow
Apple:Reds
#foo:biz
bar:cz
```

Now I don't want to read lines which start with `#`. Then I will re-write the code as

```
require 'csv'

CSV.read("#{__dir__}/test.txt", 'rb', :col_sep => ':',:skip_lines => /\A#/)
```

Let's run the code and see what it does :

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> ruby test.rb
[["Banana", "Yellow"], ["Apple", "Reds"], ["bar", "cz"]]
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby>
```

Comment: Can I ask another question that is very closely related? Let's say I have comments in the config file. How could I strip them out (comment lines begin with a "#")?

Comment: @Openmedi That's very easy.. Just do `str[0] == '#' ? str[1..-1].split(':') : str.split(':')`.. That's it..

Comment: @ArupRakshit I believe the OP means he wants to *skip* commented lines, not parse the rest of the line.